# off-topic: How can I update "Quickly" using a PPA or similar in the Source file?

Tags: application-development, ppa, quickly

I am running an ubuntu derivative that runs a bit behind in the updates. The version I'm running

```
 ~$ quickly --version
Quickly 11.10
  Python interpreter: /usr/bin/python 2.7.2
  Python standard library: /usr/lib/python2.7

  Quickly used library: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quickly
  Quickly data path: /usr/share/quickly
  Quickly detected template directories:
          /usr/share/quickly/templates/

Copyright 2009 Rick Spencer
Copyright 2009-2011 Didier Roche
Copyright 2010-2011 Canonical Ltd
https://launchpad.net/quickly

quickly comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. quickly is free software, and
you may use, modify and redistribute it under the terms of the GNU
General Public License version 3 or later.
```

I have tried finding a PPA for quickly to add to my source file list and I have found

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quickly and https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/precise/quickly/precise-updates I even found what I thought was the developers PPA http://ppa.launchpad.net/quickly/daily-build/ubuntu For the latter I get the 404 error both when is says the distribution is set to oneric or precise.

Would I need to compile the source or is there some way to add the ppa without using ubuntu?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question is off-topic, only official Ubuntu derivitives are allowed here on Ask Ubuntu. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/684/linux-mint-and-other-unofficial-derivatives-on-topic

Comment: What about this question suggests this the asker isn't running Ubuntu?

Comment: @andrewsomething "I am running an ubuntu derivative [...]" .  Which isn't to say it is necessarily *not* an official derivative.

Comment: @belacqua Eek! Somehow I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Quickly depends on multiple other packages that also have newer version in Ubuntu 12.04.  You should either upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 or install it in a virtual machine and use that for your development environment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the [download files url](https://launchpad.net/quickly/+download) in your list. Give those a try if you haven't already.